# What's the reload time on the SOFLAM?

Tags: battlefield-3

When my SOFLAM gets destroyed, I am unable to redeploy. Is there a reload time for it, or am I unable to redeploy it until I die? There's been times I've been alive for a while after it was destroyed and I was still unable to deploy again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Like a MAV, TUGS or spawn beacon, if they are destroyed you need to find an ammo box to reload your SOFLAM.

Ammo boxes are non-discriminatory. So if you see an enemy throw one down, kill him and then use it to reload. Or if you see a Support kit on the ground, swap kits, throw some ammo out for yourself, and then swap back.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't realize that.. well, knowing is half the battle(field).